# Trying to pass an 'id' of a traversed soundfile array to a play method

Tags: reactjs

What I'd like to do is pass the id of the soundfiles array, that is iterated over in the Drum class, to the method play_pauseAudio(), so that each button plays one of nine soundfiles.  I've got 'var myAudio = document.getElementById();' but don't know what to pass in that will refer to the id of each soundfile being mapped.

¬¬¬

```
  import React from 'react';

  import React from 'react';

  class Drum extends React.Component {
      super(props)
      {
          constructor(props)
      }

      play_pauseAudio = this.play_pauseAudio.bind(this);

      play_pauseAudio()
        {
            var myAudio = document.getElementById();
            myAudio.play();

        } 

      render() {
        console.log(this.props.id);
          return this.props.soundfiles.map((eachfile) => 

          <div>
              <button onClick = {this.play_pauseAudio} >Play</button>
              <audio controls source src = {eachfile.soundfileURL} style = {{width:0,height:0}} id = {eachfile.id}></audio>
          </div>
      )
    }//render
  }//class
  export default Drum;




import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Drum from './components/Drum'

class App extends React.Component {

    state =
    {
      sound_file_collection:
      [
        {
          index:0,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3',
          letter:'Q',
          description: 'PinkFloyd',
          id: "audio_id0"
        },

        {
          index:1,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3',
          letter:'W',
          description: 'Handclap',
          id: "audio_id1"
        },
        { 
          index:2,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3',
          letter: "E",
          description: 'Cymbal',
          id: "audio_id2"
        },
        { 
          index:3,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3',
          letter: 'A',
          description:'AcousticGuitar',
          id: "audio_id3"
        },
        { 
          index:4,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3',
          letter: 'S',
          description:'GlamRock',
          id: "audio_id4"
        },

        { 
          index:5,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3',
          letter: 'D',
          description: "Queen",
          id: "audio_id5"

        },
        { 
          index:6,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3',
          letter: 'Z',
          description: 'Tambourine',
          id: "audio_id6"
        },
        { 
          index:7,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3',
          letter: 'X',
          description: 'DampenedDrum',
          id: "audio_id7"
        },
        { 
          index:8,
          soundfileURL:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3',
          letter: 'C',
          description: 'MetalDrum',
          id: "audio_id8"
        }

      ]

    }//end of state

    render()
      {
        return (
        <div className="App" id="drum-machine">
        <Drum soundfiles = {this.state.sound_file_collection} />
        </div>
      );
      }
}
export default App;
//Q, W, E, A, S, D, Z, X, C.
```

¬¬¬

Comment: thanks for posting your code as an example, but it still needs a bit of formatting.  Also, can you post what is the issue you are having and what is your expected result?